# Reading the bits of a natural number from LSB to MSB without built-ins in O(n)

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

Taking a natural number a as input, it is easy to read the bits of its binary form from MSB to LSB in O(n) time, n being its binary length, using only a for loop and elementary sums and subtractions. A left shift can be achieved by a+a and subtracting 1000000...

```
def powerOfTwo(n):
  a = 1
  for j in range(0,n):
    a=(a+a)
  return a

def bitLenFast(n):
  len=0
  if (n==0):
    len=1
  else:  
    y=1
  while (y<=n):
    y=(y+y)
    len=(len+1)
  return len    

def readAsBinary(x): 
  len=bitLenFast(x)        # Length of input x in bits
  y=powerOfTwo((len-1))    # Reference word 1000000...
  hBit=powerOfTwo(len)     # Deletes highest bit in left shift
  for i in range(0, len):
    if (x>=y):
        bit=1
        x=((x+x)-hBit)    
    else:
        bit=0
        x=(x+x)
    print(bit)
```

Is there an algorithm to parse a bit by bit from LSB to MSB in O(n) time, using only a while or a for loop and elementary operations (i.e. no bitwise built-in functions or operators)?

Comment: "using only a while loop and elementary operations (i.e. no bitwise built-in functions or operators)" - I would have though bitwise operations are about as elementary as you can get....

Comment: Repeated modulo/division, store, then reverse the digits (using a stack, for example). Trade space for time.

Comment: No, no stacks. And no >> , << or &. I wouldnt call these operators elementary.

Comment: You can parse the number from MSB to LSB in O(n) without stacks, >>, << or &.

Comment: just because you can do something doesn't mean you should!

Comment: You should at any rate know if you can... or cannot.

Comment: @MarcosGonzalez why aren't they "elementary"? Current computers are binary computers so binary operations are the most basic operations in them. Even adders are made of AND/OR/XOR gates under the hood

Comment: A question tagged [tag:bit-manipulation] restricting acceptable procedures to *no bitwise built-in functions or operators*. Please be explicit about the input provided and the output required.

Comment: @tucuxi I have added my code to read from MSB to LSB in O(n)

Comment: No, you dont have to update y nor hbit. It should be valid python code, bar typos...

Comment: @tucuxi I have just tested it and it seems to work fine -- in O(n).

Comment: I stand corrected. I did not think of multiplying x by 2 (allowed) instead of dividing y by 2 (not allowed).

Comment: The problem is, how do you do it in the other direction?

Answer (score 2):

This is an implementation of [samgak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67566633/15472) in JS, using 2 calls to (an adapted version of) OP's code. Since OP's code is O(n), and all added code is O(1), the result is also O(n).

Therefore, the answer to OP's question is **yes**.

*NOTE: updated to add leading zeroes as per samgak's updated answer.*

```js
function read_low_to_high(num, out) {
   const acc = { 
      n: 0, // integer with bits in reverse order
      p: 1, // current power-of-two
      z: 0, // last run of zeroes, to prepend to result once finished
      push: (bit) => {  // this is O(1)
         if (bit) {
             acc.n = acc.n + acc.p;
             acc.z = 0;
         } else {
             acc.z = acc.z + 1;
         }
         acc.p = acc.p + acc.p;
      }
   };
                                   // with n as log2(num) ... 
   read_high_to_low(num, acc);     // O(n) - bits in reverse order
   for (let i=0; i<acc.z; i++) {   // O(n) - prepend zeroes
      out.push(0);
   }
   read_high_to_low(acc.n, out);   // O(n) - bits in expected order
}

function read_high_to_low(num, out) {
   let po2 = 1;          // max power-of-two <= num
   let binlength = 1;
   while (po2 + po2 <= num) {
      po2 = po2 + po2;
      binlength ++;
   }
   
   const hi = po2 + po2; // min power-of-two > num
   for (let i=0; i<binlength; i++) {
      if (num>=po2) {
         out.push(1);
         num = num + num - hi;
      } else {
         out.push(0);
         num = num + num;
      }
   }
}

function test(i) {
   const a = i.toString(2)
              .split('').map(i => i-'0');
   const ra = a.slice().reverse();

   const b = [];
   read_high_to_low(i, b);
   const rb = [];
   read_low_to_high(i, rb);
   console.log(i,
      "high-to-low",
      JSON.stringify(a), 
      JSON.stringify(b),
      "low-to-high",
      JSON.stringify(ra),
      JSON.stringify(rb)
   );
}

for (let i=0; i<16; i++) test(i);
```

Comment: Your code exposed a bug in my algorithm, so I've edited my answer.

Comment: Updated implementation

Answer (score 2):

Apply your algorithm to find the bits in MSB to LSB order to the number. Keep an accumulator A initialized to 0 and a place value variable B initialized to 1. At each iteration, add B to A if the bit is set and then double B by adding it to itself. You also need to keep track of the number of consecutive 0 bits. Initialize a counter C to zero beforehand and at each iteration increment it if the bit is 0 or set to zero otherwise.

At the end you will have the number with the bits reversed in A. You can then output C leading zeros and then apply the algorithm to A to output the bits of the original number in LSB to MSB order.

Comment: The advantage of this algorithm is that I don't have to argue with you about what counts as an elementary operation because you have asserted that parsing MSB to LSB can be done in O(n) with elementary operations :)

Comment: How do you test if a bit is set in O(1) with just addition?

Comment: That's a question for OP. He says parsing the bits in MSB to LSB order is possible in O(n) using elementary operations so that's a starting assumption of my answer.

Comment: Given access to OP's magical "parse the bits in MSB to LSB order in O(n) using only these tools" program, how do you test if a bit is set in O(1) with just those tools? Yes, I don't like the problem either, but if you play, you should follow the rules.

Comment: I am assuming that "parsing the bits" includes discovery of whether each bit is set without additional work. i.e. the bits are the output of that algorithm.

Comment: Upvoted, since I actually implemented this in an answer on top of OP's code, and it works as advertised.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
value = 666
while value:
    next = value // 2  # integer division
    bit = value - next * 2
    print(bit, end = " ")
    value = next

>>> 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: (funny we should get the task the opposite way around)

Comment: @greybeard  Why opposite? As far as I understand, author wants to separate the lowest bit first `from LSB to MSB`

Comment: is integer division allowed?

Comment: @tucuxi Author writes in comments  `no >> , << or &`

Comment: @tucuxi  Aha, you mean `elementary sums and subtractions`. In this case - division is not suitable perhaps, if I widened set of elementary ops too much...

Comment: (Is the task *binary digits to machine representation* or the other way around? Our answers use opposite interpretations, mine starting with `parse a [?a _what_?] bit by bit from LSB to MSB`.)

Comment: I understand the problem to be "here is an int, give me the bits one by one from LSB to MSB". In JS, something like `n => n.toString(2).reverse().split('').map(b=>b-'0')`

Comment: The problem is, integerDivision would already be in O(n), wouldnt it? And then it would be performed in every loop...

Comment: `integerDivision would already be in O(n)` - why? What about summation?

Answer (score 0):

For reading digits from least significant to most significant and determining the numerical value, there is, but for a valid assertion about run time it would be essential if e.g. *indexed access* is constant time.
For *digit*s in numerical value:

*value* ← 0, *weight* ← 1
foreach *digit*
  while 0 < *digit*
    *value* ← *value* + *weight*
    *digit* ← *digit* - 1
  *weight* ← *weight* + *weight*

Comment: For a generalisation to higher bases, introduce *base* and increment *weight*  iteratively.